# VS2010 Linker Settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

What's the difference between the settings *Link Library Dependencies* and *Link Library Dependency Inputs* found in *Linker -> General* versus the same options found under *Framework and References*?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the *Linker->General* settings only refer to project dependencies in the current solution where as *Framework and References* refers to .NET Frameworks, COM components or external projects.